# Validate data between multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL database:

```
date       | avl | occ
----------------------
2014-11-12 |  2  |  3
2014-11-13 |  0  |  5
2014-11-14 |  1  |  4
```

I am using following query to get the data from MySQL database:

```
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $check_in_date . "' AND  '" . $check_out_date . "' ORDER by avl DESC");
if ($results) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
        $avl= $row['avl'];
        $date= $row['date'];
    }
}
```

Now I want to print the `$check_in_date` only if `$avl`'s' value is greater than `0` between `$check_in_date` and `$check_out_date`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just add up another condition on the `WHERE` clause.

Example:

```
$check_in_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_in_date);
$check_out_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_out_date);
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE avl > 0 AND date BETWEEN '$check_in_date' AND '$check_out_date' ORDER by avl DESC");
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $avl = $row['avl'];
        $date = $row['date'];
    }
}
```